# pythonic way: vars in dict

Tags: python, notation

Hi python programmers,

in my script I have some settings variables, which are generated by a function and returned in a dict.
These settings vars are passed to several functions. I'm trying to write my code easy readable, so i would like to know which notation you would prefer?

```
def fooA(a,b,c):
    return a+b+c

def fooB(D,c):
    return D['a']+D['b']+c


settings = { 'a':1, 'b':2 }
c = 3

print fooA(settings['a'],settings['b'],c)
print fooB(settings,c)
```

Or do you think the best way is not to wrap the settings vars in a dict?

Comment: You shouldn't use `set` as a variable name. It will override the builtin.

Comment: @Tim: Absolutely, I changed my example!

Answer (score 2):

I'm certainly not an expert in being Pythonic, but I think this is pretty bad.

Use an object, or [a named tuple](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple), or something. The dictionary-access syntax isn't very nice for something like settings, in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

Storing settings, which are actually key-value pairs, in dictionary is absolutely OK (this is probably the best way to implement this).  As you shown in you example, your code becomes shorter and more understandable.

Django stores its settings in a dictionary.

mod_wsgi stores request environment (headers), which are actully settings, in a dictionary.

`os.environ` is a dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

Using a dict or dict-like object for settings is ok (you might want to use some custom immutable dict-like object instead but anyway...), just as would be any custom "settings" object FWIW (hint: Python objects are mostly glorified dicts...).

wrt/ your function calls, there's no one-size-fits-all answer. The first version is "better" in that it's more découpled (no dependencies on your settings, no assumption on what settings are defined etc) ) and more explicit, but some pieces of code are really tied to the application's settings and then it might make more sense to either pass the whole "settings" dict-or-object or provide a way to retrieve it.

Answer (score 0):

i think the dictionary is ok, if you would like to write settings to a human readable file you may use configparser from standard library: http://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html